# How to check if notifications is already allowed by user in google chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification, notifications, service-worker

I have a modal that pops up first asking if the user wants to receive special offers, if they click yes, then I pull in the code for push notifications so that they can allow notifications.  If they already allowed notifications I don't want the modal to pop up.  I am looking for a way to check if notifications has already been allowed by the user, using google chrome.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Check the `permission` property of the Notification object:

```
if (Notification.permission !== "granted") {
    // ask for permission
```

Comment: Thanks!  Works perfect.

Comment: Also, Notification.permission !== "denied".

Answer (score 4):

Alongside `Notification.permission` as answered by [Denys Séguret](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37973358/2014893) there is the newer, less well-supported but more general [Permissions API.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API)

Here's a quick usage example, based on [the one from MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API/Using_the_Permissions_API)

```
function handlePermission() {
    return navigator.permissions
            .query({name:'notifications'})
            .then(permissionQuery)
            .catch(permissionError);
}

function permissionQuery(result) {
    console.debug({result});
    var newPrompt;

    if (result.state == 'granted') {
        // notifications allowed, go wild

    } else if (result.state == 'prompt') {
        // we can ask the user
        newPrompt = Notification.requestPermission();

    } else if (result.state == 'denied') {
        // notifications were disabled
    }

    result.onchange = () => console.debug({updatedPermission: result});

    return newPrompt || result;
}

////

handlePermission();
```